# JComboBox update a partir de outra JComboBox

Tags: java, jcombobox

A minha ideia era fazer um JComboBox cujos valores fossem atualizados de acordo com as opções da ComboBox anterior.

Estou a usar vários ArrayLists.

Por exemplo, uma ComboBox com opção Janeiro e Fevereiro... Se escolher Janeiro na primeira ComboBox, a segunda só terá eventos de Janeiro.

Minha tela:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Que linguagens está a utilizar? Pode colocar o código que já tem aqui?

Comment: Java (a usar o Eclipse).

Comment: Confira o guia [ask]. Você é livre para **[edit]** a pergunta e acrescentar mais detalhes, adicionar tags, etc.

Comment: O código eu não coloquei pois não sei como proceder para fazer o que tenho em mente. Já me disseram que teria que ser com .toArray() mas não sei como. A parte gráfica é essa: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/38051425/Captura%20de%20tela%202014-06-17%2010.49.22.png  e a ideia era fazer esta aplicação com o tema Loja de Animais. Tenho vários arraylists. Ao escolher a categoria 'cão' em vez de gato, por exemplo, em especies, só iria aparecer as especies de cão... e por ai adiante.

Comment: De onde você vai tirar a lista de eventos do mês escolhido? Já está tudo carregado em variáveis ou vai acessar o BD? Como você faz a referencia dos eventos dependendo do mês escolhido?

Comment: Apenas dei um exemplo aplicado a meses > eventos. O meu projeto é de uma Loja de Animais. Com categorias (cão, gato, roedor, etc), especies dessas categorias (siamês, etc) e nomes de animais disponiveis com a categoria e especie escolhida.

Comment: @user não tinha visto sua resposta, aconselho usar o @ + "nome do usuário" para que o usuario possa receber uma notificação de que foi respondido. Sua dúvida ainda persiste? Acho que agora eu entendi o seu problema. Se ainda quiser uma resposta me avisa (com o @ dessa vez :P)

Answer (score 2):

Sem o teu código para ajudar torna se um pouco difícil de ajudar.

A tua `combobox` de escolha é fixa, isto é sabes qual é o elemento de cada item?

Contudo vou postar uma espécie de Pseudocódigo para ver se ajuda.
(Estou a pensar que a tua `combobox` de escolha é fixa)

```
switch (comboBox1.getSelectItem) {
            case cao:
                    comboBox2.removeAllItens();
                    for(Raça raça: Raças){
                        comboBox2.addItem("raça");
                    }                
                break;
            case ave:
                comboBox2.removeAllItens();
                    for(TipoPassaraos passaro: Passaros){
                        comboBox2.addItem("passaro");
                    }
                break;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar um Listener no primeiro ComboBox para alterar o conteúdo do segundo.
Algo parecido com isso:

```
private void configuraComboBox(){
    List<String> meses = Arrays.asList("Janeiro","Fevereiro");
    jCombobox.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(meses.toArray()));

    jCombobox.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {

            @Override
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {

               if(jCombobox.getSelectedItem() == null){
                  jCombobox2.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel<>());

               }else{
                 switch ((String)  jComboBox.getSelectedItem()) {
                    case "Janeiro":
                        jCombobox2.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel<String>(getEventosJaneiro()));
                        break;
                    case "Fevereiro":
                        jCombobox2.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel<String>(getEventosFevereiro()));
                        break;
                    default:
                       jCombobox2.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel<>());
                }
              }
            }
        });
}

private String[] getEventosJaneiro(){
    return new String[]{"Férias", "Atividade"};
}

private String[] getEventosFevereiro(){
    return  new String[]{"Carnaval", "Volta as aulas"};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa utilizar a inserção de itens em tempo de execução, para isso utilize o método addItem. Para ficar mais claro:

```
if(comboBox1.getSelectItem.toString.equals("Frutas"){
comboBox2.addItem("Maçã");
comboBox2.addItem("Pera");
}
```

Para remover:

```
comboBox1.removeAllItens();
```

Para melhores esclarecimentos:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html

Comment: .addItem ? Mas os itens são da minha ArrayList, logo não poderá ser assim.

Comment: Bem, se podesse passar seu código poderia tentar te ajudar. Pois dependendo da estrutura da sua ArrayList seria só filtar o que quer adicionar do arrayList no comboBox

Comment: O problema é que são várias arraylist e classes e nem sei que código aqui colocar. Porque tenho uma classe que armazena 3 arraylists. Fornecedores, clientes, animais. Tenho uma classe pra cada categoria de animal (cão, gato, passaro, peixe, roedor) e cada uma é subclasse da classe animal que tem o nome, categoria, data de nascimento, cor (uso aqui o enum) e preço. Na classe "vendas" em que preciso desse código para as combobox ainda só fiz a parte gráfica. Por isso é complicado dispor aqui código de forma clara... É esse o problema. Mas é esta a estrutura basicamente.